# Java Reflection - Get Current Field Value in Existing Object

Tags: java, reflection

I have a constructed object of the type below,

```
public class Form {
   private String a;
   private String b;
   private Boolean c;

   public String getA() { return a; }
   public void setA (String a) { this.a = a; }
   public String getB() { return b; }
   public void setB (String b) { this.b = b; }
   public Boolean getC() { return c; }
   public void setC (Boolean c) { this.c = c; }
}
```

I'm using reflection to examine an existing object, e.g. this Form: `("testA", "testB", False)`

How do I get the current value of a particular field, let's say `String b` ?

```
// Assume "form" is my current Form object
Field[] formFields = form.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
if (formFields != null) {
   for (Field formField : formFields) { 
       Class type = formField.getType();
       // how do I get the current value in this current object?
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use methods of [`java.lang.reflect.Field`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html):

```
// Necessary to be able to read a private field
formField.setAccessible(true);

// Get the value of the field in the form object
Object fieldValue = formField.get(form);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a situation where I am a big proponent of using an external library.  Apache Commons BeanUtils is excellent for this purpose and hides a lot of the core java.lang.reflect complexity.  You can find it here:  http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/

Using BeanUtils, the code to satisfy your need would be the following:

```
Object valueOfB = PropertyUtils.getProperty( formObject, "b" );
```

Another benefit of using BeanUtils is that it does all of the checking to ensure that you have a proper accessor method for "b" -- getB().  There are also other utility methods in the BeanUtils library which enable you to handle all sorts of Java bean property manipulation.

Comment: Thank you, this works, but it only returns a String. I may need a specific Object returned.

Comment: My apologies.  I've updated the answer.  I thought you only wanted a String specifically.  I've updated my answer.  If you use PropertyUtils (which is within that library), you will have a raw Object returned to you.